# How to change all values in a csv file cloumn using python using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataset

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
                                          Title_name  ...  Check
0  Did 7 Children Die in Senegal from COVID-19 Va...  ...  False
1   Should Fabric Masks Be Sanitized in a Microwave?  ...  False
2  Is Mike Pence Waving a Confederate Flag in Thi...  ...  False
3  Is Bill Gates Being Sued by India Over Vaccina...  ...  False
4       Did the New York Jets Sign Colin Kaepernick?  ...  False

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to change the value of "Check" Column from False to Fake i tried to use

`df['Check'] = df.Check.str.replace('False', 'True')`

I got an error of datatype something like this

```
raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I saw some solutions using csv file , but was wondering how can I use pandas and replace all cloumn values without headers.

Comment: the check column is a boolean dtype, so string replace wont work. try [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) instead

Comment: Your column "Check" is boolean type (has only 2 values True and False), so basically in case you want to change False into True, the whole column would equal True. You can achieve this `df['Check'] = True`

Answer (score 1):

Yours is almost correct. The thing is that pandas detects False as a boolean. That's why it gives you that error. You just have to first change the type to string. Like this:

```
#First change the type to string
df['Check'] = df.Check.astype(str).str.replace('False', 'True')

#You can also change it to Fake
#df['Check'] = df.Check.astype(str).str.replace('False', 'Fake')
```

Comment: Thanks this is worked perfectly fine , correct me if am understanding it worng but astype() forces it to be string??

Answer (score 0):

The type of column Check is boolean. You can check

```
df.Check.dtype
```

If you want to use replace

```
df.astype(str).replace('False','True')
```